# PDFbox loading same pdf files when inside a loop in each iteration

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, intellij-idea, pdfbox

I am facing an issue when I try to load multiple pdf files.

So I have multiple files constructed and I return them in a list as multipart files, I loop through and in each iteration I load the document by using `load` function like this PDDocument.load(multipartFile.getBytes()).

This is the code that is not working as intended inside a loop.

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(multipartFile.getBytes())) {
    System.out.println(multipartFile.getBytes().length);
    System.out.println(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    System.out.println(document.hashCode());
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println(document.getDocumentInformation().getTitle());
    System.out.println(document.getNumberOfPages());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could give me some direction on how to solve this issue. I spent a couple days debugging.

I tried to debug,
`Byte length`, `multipartFile name` and document `hash code` is different in each iteration but when i try to access document `information` or `document number of pages` is always the same and when i save the document is always the first pdf.

Comment: PDFBox version that i am using is `2.0.27`

Comment: Try to recreate the problem with some complete and working code and print the hash of the bytes `System.out.println(Hex.getString(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(multipartFile.getBytes()))); `

Comment: I did print the hash of multipart files and in each iteration its a different one.

Comment: Lets say i have 3 files: file1, file2 and file3. I did reverse the list by using `Collections.reverse(createdUnits);` and i was expecting that the last one (file3) will be loaded to document in each iteration but it did not, instead file1.pdf is loaded in each iteration again. This is strange, can it be something with cache? There is no cache mechanism implemented by me.

Comment: You need to create and share a sample project with files with different page count. PDFBox has some caching mechanism but not at file level.

Comment: Obviously, `multipartFile` isn't a `File` but something else (maybe a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?). Could it be you're writing bytes into that thing, but you're writing towards the end and forgot to reset it in each loop iteration?

Comment: Also what happens if you save the bytes (not the PDDocument) into 3 different files and try to open these. Re my previous comment - that one is disproved by your reverse() attempt. I'm still wondering how multipartBytes gets fillled. That's why it's important to create a small self-working project.